# understanding topological argument in rado-kneser theorem

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, analysis

Rado-kneser choquet theorem states that Poisson integral of a homeomorphism of unit circle is a homeomorphism. It's proof goes like proving it local homeomorphism by proving non vanishing of jacobian at a point.
Then proving it 1-1 and onto. I am having doubt in one-one part.
Since $f$ is continuous , so inverse image of each point is compact and therefore finite. I am done till this point. Now it says every point has same number of pre-images. How do I prove that? Secondly, after that using simple connectedness  it says number of pre-images is 1. How to prove this. Any hint is appreciated.